# Idiomatic use of stdout as alternative

Tags: python, stdin, with-statement

Is this idiomatic?

```
with open(output_file, 'w') if output_file else sys.stdout as outf:
    outf.write("hello")
```

Will the `with` block cause trouble to `stdout` (by closing it)?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out whether `sys.stdout.closed`? Would save you some typing here.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin indeed, but I am busy and thought that maybe somebody was interested in getting the points for solving this. Besides, I think it is a good question to have an answer for it online. Trading time for points - which cost me nothing :)

Comment: Aaaand, I also like to see how people solve problems I encounter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to write to stdout after that, it will:

```
>>> import sys
>>> output_file = None
>>> with open(output_file, 'w') if output_file else sys.stdout as outf:
...     outf.write("hello")
... 
hello5
>>> print("test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The only way this could somehow safely be used would be as the last statement in a script where you know that `stdout` will not be used later, e.g:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     output_file = ... # parse arguments
     with open(output_file, 'w') if output_file else sys.stdout as outf:
         outf.write("hello")
```

But even that feels wrong. Better: separate opening and working with the file, and be explicit about it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     output_file = ... # parse arguments
     if output_file:
         with open(output_file, 'w') as outf:
             do_stuff(outf)
     else:
             do_stuff(sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Nice, but calling `do_stuff` in two different places just because I am passing a different parameter seems a bit odd. I would maybe collect `outf = open(output_file, 'w')` and at the end close the file descriptor manually: `outf.close()` (if not stdout). A bit more writing, but a single call to `do_stuff`